# MAAS 1.9.1 GUI Taskbar missing Network TAB on Ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: networking, server, maas

I deployed MAAS 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 but all the install guides showing MASS GUI having Network Tab ie
Nodes-Cluster-Images-Zones-Network-Settings

but i am seeing the GUI Taskbar option below

Nodes-Cluster-Images-Zones- ***SUBNETS*** -Settings
ie Subnets instead of Networks

Is there something wrong here or do i need to install any more packages etc....

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MAAS interface eth0 (External) and eth1 (internal)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/757804/maas-interface-eth0-external-and-eth1-internal)

Comment: actually a different question and wondering if the Network Tab is now replaced with Subnets Tab in MAAS GUI......Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you install Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS you will see the Network tab. I ran in to same issue but when I install 16.04 then I lost Cluster tab, still trying to figure it out..