# MAAS interface eth0 (External) and eth1 (internal)

Tags: networking, server, maas, dhcp

I have two interfaces configured in MAAS under Cluster
eth0 - external IP VLAN 10
eth1 - internal (10.x.x.x) VLAN 20  - DHCP-DNS Managed

I am going to add a node in MAAS.....I have setup the node (machine) to boot from Network (PXE).....Node has two Interface 
eth0 - VLAN 10
eth1 - VLAN 30

Qs:
1. Does the MAAS server eth1 connects with eth1 of new node automatically when i power up the Node......
2. Do both eth1 has to be on the same VLAN
3. Or MAAS will install the new NOde thru eth0 which are on same VLAN and assign internal IP from its DHCP to eth0 of the New Node.....

Right now if i reboot the New Node it is keep looking for a boot server and timing out......

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A1. No, since they are on different VLANs 20 and 30. Both MAAS server as well as the nodes to be managed by MAAS should be in the same network or VLAN or whatever.

A2. Yes, that's right!

A3. Since, MAAS is managing DHCP and DNS on eth1 (of MAAS server), it will not manage the network it is connected to through eth0.
If you want MAAS server to manage nodes on eth0, it should be allowed to run its DHCP and DNS services on that interface too.

Please correct me if I am wrong.
Hope it helps!!
But, then if there is already a DHCP or DNS server running on that network then it will get messed up.

Comment: Perfect ...... make sense... I have updated the VLAN to keep all my private network on it and now nodes PXE boot and gets its IP from MAAS......Thank you

Comment: May you please confirm the answer as correct, if you feel so. So that I get some reputation. Thank you.